# Lotus Notes Java API mistake with encoding

Tags: java, encoding, lotus-notes

I'm newble in Java and I need to extract data from `NSF` files to `DXL` xml files. I tried it with python, but OLE wrapper doesn't have a few major functionality. I have two different formates of `DXL` files: with `rawitemdata` and with `richtext`.

When I switched to Java Lotus Notes API I receive mistakes in `rawitemdata` fields. I use `doc.convertToMIME(2);` procedure to provide mail body in the `HTML` format for getting sameness for each type of documents. As result all fields stored as `rawitemdata` and it's great. It's what I want. But some `rawitemdata` fields have crashed encoding.

It's look like

```
<rawitemdata type="19">
AgAPAAAAAgAmAj4AhQEAAAAAAAANCi0tMF9fPUNDQkIwRTFFREZBRjk4Mjg4ZjllOGE5M2RmOTM4NjkwOTE4Y0NDQkIwRTFFREZBRjk4
MjgNCkNvbnRlbnQtVHJhbnNmZXItRW5jb2Rpbmc6IGJpbmFyeQ0KQ29udGVudC10eXBlOiBhcHBsaWNhdGlvbi9vY3RldC1zdHJlYW07
IA0KCW5hbWU9Ij0/S09JOC1SP0I/OFBMdjlPL3I3K3d1Wkc5amVBPT0/PSINCkNvbnRlbnQtRGlzcG9zaXRpb246IGF0dGFjaG1lbnQ7
IGZpbGVuYW1lPSI9P0tPSTgtUj84UEx2OU8vcjcrd3VaRzlqZUE9PT89Ig0KQ29udGVudC1JRDogPDNfXz1DQ0JCMEUxRURGQUY5ODI4
OGY5ZThhOTNkZjkzODY5MDkxQGxvY2FsPg0KDQoFzwXQBc4F0gXOBcoFzgXLLmRvY3g=
</rawitemdata>
```

After decode from **base64** I got this

```
\x02\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00&\x02>\x00\x85\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\r\n-
-0__=CCBB0E1EDFAF98288f9e8a93df938690918cCCBB0E1EDFAF9828\r\nContent-Transfer-Encoding: 
binary\r\nContent-type: application/octet-stream; \r\n\tname="=?KOI8-R?B?8PLv9O/r7+wuZG9jeA==?
="\r\nContent-Disposition: attachment; filename="=?KOI8-R?8PLv9O/r7+wuZG9jeA==?="\r\nContent-ID: 
<3__=CCBB0E1EDFAF98288f9e8a93df93869091@local>\r\n\r\n\x05\xcf\x05\xd0\x05\xce\x05\xd2\x05\xce\x05\xca\x
05\xce\x05\xcb.docx
```

It's easy to explain:

- first 20 bytes it's a header: `\x02\x00\x0f\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00&\x02>\x00\x85\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`

  > to unpack it I use next code `struct.unpack("<hhhh hhLL", data[:20])`
  >   it returns tuple like this: `(2, 15, 0, 2, 550, 62, 389, 0)` where the 5th element it is a length of body. But I changed the body and lazed to calc current header for new body
- the body with rfc822 headers

After **base64** and then **koi8-r** header `Content-Disposition` decoded we could see field **name** with content `ПРОТОКОЛ.docx`. And it's correct content.

If I try decode the last part of the body which contains byte encoding `\x05\xcf\x05\xd0\x05\xce\x05\xd2\x05\xce\x05\xca\x
05\xce\x05\xcb.docx` I got exception. This is part can't being decoded correctly.
It's look like **cp1251** encoding under **unicode**. Because the content `ПРОТОКОЛ.docx` in **cp1251** codepage has '\xcf\xd0\xce\xd2\xce\xca\xce\xcb.docx' bytes.

My java code is quite simple:

```java
import lotus.domino.Database;
import lotus.domino.Session;
import lotus.domino.NotesFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;

import lotus.domino.*;

public class ExportDXL {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String server = "";
        String dbPath = "C:\\share\\test.nsf";

        NotesThread.sinitThread();
        Session session = NotesFactory.createSession((String)null, (String)null, "test");

        Database db = session.getDatabase(server, dbPath);
        System.out.println("Db Title: " + db.getTitle());
        DxlExporter exporter = session.createDxlExporter();
        exporter.setConvertNotesBitmapsToGIF(true);

        View view = db.getView("$ALL");

        Document doc = view.getFirstDocument();

        while(doc != null){
            doc.convertToMIME(2); // or set 1 for get plain text

            String xmldoc = doc.generateXML();

            FileWriter fw = null;
            String id = doc.getUniversalID();
            fw = new FileWriter("C:\\lotus_test\\"+ id +".xml");
            fw.write(xmldoc);
            fw.flush();
            fw.close();

            doc = view.getNextDocument(doc);

        }
    }
}
```

How can I provide correct encoding in this case? Or how to set code page for `Lotus Notes API` ?

Comment: The content-transfer-encoding is binary and the content-type is octet-stream. That means that the body of MIME part is a binary file. Your job is not to encode or decode it. Your job is to faithfully store the octet values in a file.

Comment: Thank You, @RichardSchwartz! I can store it anyway. But any other app can't use this data correctly. I think `Lotus Notes API` has mistake when it preared data for this section. I tried to switch internal java codepage to `cp1251` but nothing changed. If I didn't use `convertToMIME` I wouldn't have this encoding mistake.

Comment: Did this document originate in Notes? Or was it sent from a non-Notes system and received by a Domino server? It's not clear to me that the encoding error is the fault of Notes and Domino. Whenever processing emails that may have come from the outside, it is necessary to consider the possibility that the originating system may not have encoded correctly or even generated bad MIME formatting.